# Remove Objects Containing certain Data from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

We are all well aware that we can insert a vast array of datatypes into a python list. For eg. a list of characters

```
X=['a','b','c']
```

To remove 'c' all i have to do is

```
X.remove('c')
```

Now What I need is to remove an object containing a certain string.

```
class strng:
    ch = ''
    i = 0
X = [('a',0),('b',0),('c',0)]              #<---- Assume The class is stored like this although it will be actually stored as object references
Object = strng()
Object.ch = 'c'
Object.i = 1
X.remove('c')                    #<-------- Basically I want to remove the Object containing ch = 'c' only. 
                                 #           variable i does not play any role in the removal
print (X)
```

## Ans I want:

```
[('a',0),('b',0)]                   #<---- Again Assume that it can output like this
```

Comment: You are removing the `Object` itself, form your list which since your list doesn't contain your object nothing will change. For getting the expected output you need to remove the items based on your object's attributes.

Comment: @Kasramvd is right. Can you describe the role of `Object.i`?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake on my part. I've edited the code is it clear now?
Code doesn't actually run. But I hope you understood what I'm trying to do

Comment: This would not work since even if too objects have the same `obj.ch` and `obj.i` values they will not come out as equal. For that you will need to define the `__eq__` attribute of your class. Then you can remove objects.

Comment: @Aguy Oh so what your saying is I can never match an object with another object of the same class containing the same values??? Also I've never written an __eq__() function before.

Comment: I do believe so. If you want two objects with the same values to be considered equal you need to define `__eq__` to yield `True` when this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
>>> class MyObject:
...    def __init__(self, i, j):
...      self.i = i
...      self.j = j
...    def __repr__(self):
...       return '{} - {}'.format(self.i, self.j)
...
>>> x = [MyObject(1, 'c'), MyObject(2, 'd'), MyObject(3, 'e')]
>>> remove = 'c'
>>> [z for z in x if getattr(z, 'j') != remove]
[2 - d, 3 - e]
```

Comment: You need to use print in that last statement for it to work. Thanks, exactly what I wanted :D

Answer (score 1):

The following function will remove **in place** all the items for them condition is `True`:

```
def remove(list,condtion):
    ii = 0
    while ii < len(list):
        if condtion(list[ii]):
            list.pop(ii)
            continue        
        ii += 1
```

Here how you can use it:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self,ch,ii):
        self.ch = ch
        self.ii = ii
    def __repr__(self):
        return '({0},{1})'.format(self.ch,self.ii)

things = [ Thing('a',0), Thing('b',0) , Thing('a',1), Thing('b',1)]     
print('Before ==> {0}'.format(things))         # Before ==> [(a,0), (b,0), (a,1), (b,1)]
remove( things , lambda item : item.ch == 'b')
print('After  ==> {0}'.format(things))         # After  ==> [(a,0), (a,1)]
```

Comment: Nice  lamda function. But getattr() seems cleaner to me. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

For the list

```
X = [('a',0),('b',0),('c',0)]
```

If you know that the first item of a tuple is always a string, and you want to remove that string if it has a distinct value, then use a list comprehension:

```
X = [('a',0),('b',0),('c',0)] 

X = [(i,j) for i, j in X if i != 'c']

print (X)
```

Outputs the following:

```
[('a', 0), ('b', 0)]
```